# Windows Phone 7 buttons with images

Tags: c#, image, button, windows-phone-7

How do I programmatically create buttons with images on them. I want to store the buttons with images in memory representing all possible cards in a card game. Then, when I display the dealt cards to the player I can select the right card from my array of all possible cards.

```
Button[] cardButtons = new Button[52];
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    cardButtons[i] = new Button();
    cardButtons[i] = new Image(.... I dont know what goes here, or if any of this is correct!)
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .Content property of the Button class.

```
Button[] cardButtons = new Button[52];
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri("/images/someImage.png", UriKind.Relative);  
   BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
   Image image = new Image();
   image.Source = imgSource;
   cardButtons [i] = new Button();
   cardButtons[i].Content = image;
}
```